# WEKA - SimpleKMeans - Manually choose intitial centres

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a way in the WEKA explorer to manually select the initial centres when using SimpleKMeans clustering?

Comment: why would you want to choost your centres "manually" , they are assigned at random locations and they are re-assigned after each iteration of the clustering algorithm , so there is no point in "manually" initializing the centres.

Comment: I understand that is how they are usually selected. However, I was told I had to set the initial centres for an assignment and could not find a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

there is an -init option for that

*Initialization method to use.
  0 = random, 1 = k-means++, 2 = canopy, 3 = farthest first.
  (default = 0)*
kmeans++ will give you an option for you to initialize centres.